# Force PHP composer to create relative, not absolute, symlinks of local repositories

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I have a docker container with a host's directories mapped like this - 
***/app*** (project itself) and ***/packages*** (local dependencies). Then I have ***/app/composer.json*** file in which I define local repositories which reside in ***/packages*** like this

```
"require": {
    "myvendor/mypackage": "^1.0",
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./../packages/mypackage"
    }
]
```

The problem is that after running composer install/update it symlinks my packages with an absolute path so ***/app/vendor/myvendor/mypackage*** directory is symlinked as ***/packages/mypackage***. While that's working from the composer's point of view I would prefer it to be a relative symlink  - ***../../../packages/mypackage*** - because otherwise my IDE is not able to index ***mypackage*** source code (different absolute paths on my Ubuntu host than they are inside docker's container) unless I change the symlink path manually. I was looking for composer's configuration options to force absolute/relative with no luck. Is there any way to accomplish what I want, am I missing something?

Comment: Am I correct to interpret this question as "How do I configure my IDE to include third party package source code for searching and exploring?" . The relative to absolute mumbo jumbo looks like an xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why not install the packages the usual way? Why not use that `url` path to point to a properly mounted path?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am installing them the usual way. Also I know I can explicitly add source paths in IDE. As I wrote in the other comment - the question here is - is it possible to force composer to create symlinks of local vendors with relative paths instead of absolute

Comment: It seems you are overcomplicating things here. Locally, when developing, run `composer install` on your machine. Paths will be fine and you'll be able to develop as intended. On any other environment (container, different host), just run `install` again so the project is on valid state. You normally wouldn't have this problem and would be able to treat the whole `vendor` as an "artefact", but local repositories are meant mostly for development, so those expectations no longer apply.

Comment: I feel your pain. I had the same problem. I mount "myvendor/mypackage" source directory with same absolute path both in container and my local machine. It worked for me. As far as I understand composer checks common path between your package and your dependency package and this common path is '/'. In such cases compose made absolute link instead of relative. It's a bit ugly but I wasn't able to force composer to create relative link.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this problem simply by making sure the target dir (with the dev. packages) is symlinked to the same link in both environments.

E.g. if your dev packages are in /home/micper/packages, create a symlink:

```
ln -s /home/micper/packages /opt/php/packages
```

Then add the same logic to your docker config:

```
      volumes:
        - /home/micper/packages:/opt/php/packages
```

Lastly, add the source dir to your `composer.json`:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/opt/php/packages/myvendorname/mypackage"
        }
    ]
```

Note: `/opt/php/packages` is arbitrary. You can choose any other link location that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to symlinks, you can configure composer to mirror the local path instead of creating a symlink, with `COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1` environnent variable.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-mirror-path-repos

It may not be what you really need, because change in the local package will not be propagated automatically and will require to run composer install again for the local path to be mirrored again.